# Windows install not bootable from USB

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I have a W7 install .iso file. I tried to set up the bootable USB by simply copying the files in the .iso on the USB and the other approach was to use `winusb`. When booting the computer the boot menu shows two entries of the USB (don't know why), when choosing the first one, the boot menu disappears for a second and shows up again!? When choosing the second entry it says that there are no files to be executed.
I get the same result with both methods, just copying the files and using winusb!

The files on the USB are the following:

```
 Folders:
 boot
 efi
 sources
 support
 upgrade

 Files:
 autorun.inf
 bootmgr
 bootmgr.efi
 localpacks.reg
 setup.exe
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing or can do different?

Comment: you cannot copy the iso to the USB that won't work (as you can see)

Comment: I didn't copy the iso to the USB, I extracted the files first and then copied them! But also winusb didn't work and that did seem to do the same thing more or less!?

Comment: I don't think it works like that either. You would need to loopmount the iso, not extract it.

Comment: if you are not using win8 or efi I think you might be able to use unetbootin also according to this link you should be able to use dd http://askubuntu.com/a/365661/167115

Comment: @mchid I did a loopmount, sry I guess 'extract' was the wrong expression

Comment: use unetbootin or dd. unetbootin is more reliable because it usually creates a bootloader when one is not present dd might not and also, that sounds like your problem (no bootloader)

Comment: @mchid No its Win7 and efi (I listed the files on the USB now above

Comment: @mchid ok I'll try it with unetbootin

Comment: mybad, I got unetbootin to work, had to use an older version and install shared libs and it installed to the USB just fine but when I rebooted it said no boot file.

Comment: I have tried unetbootin now, and it just creates the bootloader files but doesn't do anything with the selected .iso file!?

Comment: @KasiyA I have already tried winusb as described multiple times above! It copied the files to the usb drive but the booting doesn't work...

Comment: Try another methods from other answers.